# Can I assume that a Vierbeiner is a Hund?

Tags: word-choice, etymology

An article in today's FAZ has the title: *[Arbeiten mit Vierbeinern: Darf der Hund ins Büro?](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/beruf-chance/beruf/hunde-im-buero-verbessern-das-betriebsklima-15531541-p2.html)*

A random page of Google results for *Vierbeiner* brings up these webpage titles:

- Bühne frei für Vierbeiner
- Ein Herz für Vierbeiner
- Welcher Zahnpastageschmack macht Vierbeiner glücklich?
- 1974 Euro für Vierbeiner
- Vierbeinerzentrum Nordheide

In all these pages the *Vierbeiner* are dogs, and only dogs. Can I therefore assume that the other page titles that contain the word *Vierbeiner* are also about dogs? Here are a few pages that I haven't opened:

- Barbra Streisands Vierbeiner sind erst der Anfang
- Rund um den Vierbeiner: Hitzefrei durch den Sommer
- Verreisen mit dem Vierbeiner
- Herzlich Willkommen, Vierbeiner!
- Viel Streit um Vierbeiner

And a supplementary question: When did *Vierbeiner* start to become essentially synonymous with *Hund*?

Comment: No, that's not a synonym for _"Hund"_. It applies to all animals with four legs.

Comment: But if I said: _Eine meiner Studentinnen hat heute ihren Vierbeiner mit in die Klasse gebracht_ would you automatically assume I was referring to her dog.

Comment: It could have been her cat as well. It's not a synonym but a generalization.

Comment: Agreed, or her rabbit, or giraffe for that matter. I'm trying to get a sense of whether native German speakers assume that Vierbeiner are dogs unless the context suggests otherwise.

Comment: I am a native speaker, and I do not.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've had a quick look at the first 10 Google pages of results for Vierbeiner, and estimate that between 80%-90% are about dogs only.

Comment: [Interesting results](https://www.google.de/search?q=ist+vierbeiner+synonym+f%C3%BCr+hund&oq=ist+vierbeiner+synonym+f%C3%BCr+hundhttps://www.google.de/search?q=ist+vierbeiner+synonym+f%C3%BCr+hund&oq=ist+vierbeiner+synonym+f%C3%BCr+hund), yes.

Comment: It amuses me to translate some of these titles into English: _Travelling with your quadruped. Quadrupeds welcome! Much ado about quadrupeds._

Comment: "*I'm trying to get a sense of whether native German speakers assume that Vierbeiner are dogs unless the context suggests otherwise.*" I think it is the contrary: native speakers do **not** assume that Vierbeiner are dogs, unless the context suggest otherwise like the article mentioned in the first sentence of the question.

Comment: Shoe, I think it is important to be aware that the word "Vierbeiner" is used practically exclusively in journalistic text genres, usually out of a mania of using synonyms. No normal person would say "Vierbeiner" in everyday contexts, unless, perhaps in order to be ironic (which then however again is a reference to journalistic [bad] style). - There are a number of such whims of journalists, e.g. "Grautier" for *Esel*, "Mainmetropole" for *Frankfurt*. These are words you will find only in newspapers.

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann. Thanks. This confirms my suspicion that the synonym obsession is indeed an example of German journalese (see my comment below the accepted answer). I've also noticed in it sports journalism where it seems unthinkable, for example, to write more than 10 words about "Bayern München" before switching to "_Der Rekordmeister_":  https://www.eurosport.de/fussball/bundesliga/2017-2018/fc-bayern-thomas-tuchel-sagt-rekordmeister-angeblich-ab_sto6689336/story.shtml

Comment: @Shoe Exactly! Sports reporting is a good example for a genre heavily infected with synonymitis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Vierbeiner) it's suggested that "Vierbeiner" primarily refers to dogs (all emphasis mine):

> **Bedeutungen:**
>
> [1] umgangssprachlich: Tier mit vier Beinen, **vor allem Hund**

Though [dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/german-english/Vierbeiner.html) does leave it with a more generic interpretation:

> Vierbeiner {m}
>   - quadruped zool.
>   Vierbeiner {m} [**Hund oder Katze**]
>   - four-legged friend

As mentioned, while "Vierbeiner" is mostly used as a synonym for ***dog*** colloquially in german, it still can't be really considered as a synonym, but is merely a generalization.

From a biological ([taxonomical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomy_(biology))) point of view, it simply describes an animal with a four leg body shape, and there's a number of animals falling into that category (cats, giraffes, horses, cows, etc.).

The main distinction is probably based upon the kind of locomotion, and how the limbs are used for it.

A *"Zweibeiner"* (higher order primate) uses only two legs (limbs) to move, while a "Vierbeiner" uses all four, and they keep contact to the ground.

As a native speaker, I'd not take the term "Vierbeiner" as a synonym for "dog", even not for left out context.

Comment: Thanks. I was searching for advice earlier about keeping Wildschweine out of my garden. Already in the first sentence of the first article I found that the Wildschweine had become Borstentiere. In another article it wasn't long before the Wildschweine became Paarhufer. German writers seem to have a greater need to synonymize than their English counterparts. I can't imagine an English writer suddenly switching from boars to ungulates.

Comment: @Shoe The german language can be very florid when it comes to synonymy :-D.

Answer (score 9):

#### [Vierbeiner](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Vierbeiner)

This colloquial term for all animals on four legs appeared in the second half of the 19th Century and became increasingly popular in the 20th century (source [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Vierbeiner&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CVierbeiner%3B%2Cc0))).

Mostly today we refer to dogs when talking about a *Vierbeiner* but there are many references to other animals too, they need not to be pets:

> - Bei 60 **Pferden** und damit 30 Prozent der insgesamt 200 gemeldeten **Vierbeiner** wurden Proben entnommen.<sup>[Die Zeit](http://www.zeit.de/news/2016-08/29/sport-allgemein-reiter-weltverband-meldet-alle-dopingproben-in-rio-negativ-29113605)</sup>
> - **Waschbär**, **Grauhörnchen** und **Kleinem Mungo** geht es in Europa an den Pelz. Die EU-Kommission hat diese **Vierbeiner** am Mittwoch in Brüssel auf eine Liste unerwünschter Tier- und Pflanzenarten gesetzt. <sup>[Die Zeit](http://www.zeit.de/news/2016-07/13/umwelt-waschbaeren-unerwuenscht-eu-will-fremde-arten-abwehren-13151008)</sup>
> - Als einziges **Rentier**rudel Italiens sind Rudi und Kelly, die Stars im weitläufigen Rentiergehege auf der Rotwand, mit ihren Familien längst lokale Berühmtheiten. Zuhause in der wilden Natur der Dolomitenregion Drei Zinnen, sorgen die wuscheligen **Vierbeiner** hier oben immer wieder für amüsante und faszinierende Begegnungen und sind sogar auf der Skipiste anzutreffen. <sup>[Die Zeit](http://www.zeit.de/angebote/suedtirol/familie/rentierfuetterung)</sup>
> - Kein Problem ist es dagegen, quer über die **Schaf**weiden zu wandern: Auge in Auge mit den blökenden **Vierbeinern**, die sich aber nicht aus der Ruhe bringen lassen. <sup>Tagesspiegel 29.02.2004</sup>

So no, without a clearcut context we can not assume a *Vierbeiner* always is a dog. If in a furniture shop we may even talk about a chair on four legs.

Comment: *Vierbeiner* doesn't even necessarily relate to animals at all - A four-legged stool could also be denoted as such if compared to a three-legged one.

Comment: @tofro: quote or it did not happen ;) I do know of *dreibeiniger* v. *vierbeiniger Hocker* so it could in theory be but I never heard a stool being called *Vierbeiner*

Comment: First 20 Google results: https://www.werkhaus.de/shop/wohnen/Sitzmoebel/Photohocker/Kinderhocker/Vierbeiner--Tiger-.html or (absolutely unrelated to animals): https://www.segmueller.de/Moebel/Esszimmer/Barhocker.html (search for "Vierbeiner"). And another one: https://www.steinmetz-bueromoebel.de/Sedus-meet-chair-mt-222-Vierbeiner. I hope that's happening enough.

Comment: And just for the fun of it, consider: https://www.welt.de/print-welt/article164365/Motorradfahrer-stuerzt-ueber-Hund-mit-Hocker.html Did the accident occur with the dog or the stool?

Comment: @tofro: LOL - "setz Dich doch mal auf unseren Vierbeiner, der ist super-bequem!"

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the amusing comments. I like the image of the Hocker, der sich aus dem Staub machte!

Answer (score 0):

It generally means dog, but can deviate based on context:

> **Vierbeiner, m.** vierbeiniges Tier, besonders Hund [(Source: Duden)](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Vierbeiner)
>
> *four-legged animal, especially a dog*

However, its usage is debatable. Wolf Schneider, the renowned German writing-style teacher, writes in *Deutsch für junge Profis*:

> Für die meisten konkreten Hauptwörter steht ein sauberes Synonym nicht zur Verfügung. Für den Tisch zum Beispiel. «Vierbeiner»? Der ist schon vergeben: im Schulaufsatz- und Zeitungsjargon für den Hund (ziemlich töricht noch dazu, da auch Kühe, Ameisenbären und Krokodile vier Beine haben).
>
> *There is no obvious synonym for most concrete nouns. Take "table", for example: «Vierbiener»? This term is already taken by "dog", in school essays and newspaper jargon (and foolishly, I might add, since cows, anteaters, and crocodiles also have four legs).*

Above, I have translated to English.

Answer (score -1):

**Zweibeiner** is a common "humorous" term for **humans**.

**Vierbeiner** is the analogous term for **pets**, mostly cats and dogs. If a vet or animal asylum writes this, they don't do horses, cows or other cattle. At least not usually. It also includes bunnies, guinea pigs, hamsters and pet birds, too, usually.

There's also **Dreibeiner**, an also "homorous" term for **men**, introduced by comedian *Hella von Sinnen* thirty years ago.

Comment: _"pet birds"_ Huh??

Comment: It makes no sense, but they say they care about *Vierbeiner*. Then they don't do horses, but budgies. Who knows?

Comment: _"Then they don't do horses"_ Well, a horse isn't a "Vierbeiner"? Where did you get that conclusion from?

Comment: From practical experience. Vets that do horses don't call them *Vierbeiner*.

Comment: _"Vets that do horses don't call them Vierbeiner."_ I don't see any evidence though.

Comment: Hat nicht Gaby Köster den Begriff »Dreibein« schon vor Hella von Sinnen verwendet? Ich assoziiere das Wort *Dreibein* ganz klar mit Gaby Köster, und zumindest diese Quelle gibt mir recht: https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/28421-Dreibein

Comment: Ich bitte um die Nennung von Beispielen für Vierbeiner die Vögel sind.

Comment: Gibt's nicht. Wenn jemand *Vierbeiner* schreibt, meint er jedoch üblicherweise nicht *Tiere mit vier Beinen*, sondern **Kleintiere** oder **Haustiere**. Im Gegensatz zu *Wildtieren* und *Nutztieren*.

Comment: Echt? Ich nicht. Wenn ich von Vierbeinern rede, dann meine ich Tiere oder Dinge, die vier Beine haben. Wieso bloß?

Comment: Du sagst: Ich mag *Vierbeiner*. Ich sage: Ich habe nen Kanari. Du sagst: Ich meinte Haustiere, generell.

Comment: @Janka _"sondern **Kleintiere** oder **Haustiere**"_ Das ist Unsinn! Wenn Du schon so etwas behauptest, dann unterfüttere das bitte mit geeigneten Quellen.

Comment: Der Grund, warum ihr euch so verzweifelt an euren Quellen festhaltet, ist, dass sie nicht eurem tatsächlichen Sprachgebrauch entsprechen.

Comment: Das ist ein falscher Umkehrschluss. Jemand, der von 4-Beinern spricht, aber dabei keine Krokodile meint, hat wahrscheinlich nicht `alle Sorten Vierbeiner` gesagt sondern nur einige Sorten gemeint, aber Vögel, Fische und 1000füßler ausgeschlossen. Wenn Vögel mitgemeint sind, dann hapert es wohl mit dem Zählen und erklärt, wieso man im Tierasyl gelandet ist. Ganz unabhängig von der Bezeichung haben Tierasyle selten Kühe rumstehen.

Comment: Das ist ein doppelt falscher Umkehrschluss, denn *Vierbeiner* ist eine Variation, um nicht *Hund*, *Katze* oder eben *Haustier* sagen zu müssen. Leider ist es so, dass man Hyperkorrekturen schlecht wieder einfangen kann, wenn sie einmal in Freiheit sind.

Comment: Trotzdem meint "Vierbeiner" immer nur Haustiere mit genau diesen vier Beinen.

Comment: Das ist eine Hyperkorrektur.